# Jasmine Spy called incorrectly

Tags: testing, jasmine, lit-element, spy, removeeventlistener

I'm running into an interesting problem. I have set up a jasmine spy on an event listener that I attach and detach during the lifecycle of the component (this is in lit element by the way). On the connected callback I attach it like this:

```
getPositionEvent = this.getPosition.bind(this);
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.getPositionEvent, true);
}
```

I later detach it like this:

```
disconnectedCallback() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getPositionEvent, true);
}
```

I can see during testing of the code that the attachment works here:

```
let getPositionEventSpy: jasmine.Spy;

beforeAll(() => {
  (code setting up component)
  getPositionEventSpy = spyOn(component, 'getPositionEvent');
}

beforeEach(async () => {
    component.connectedCallback();
    await component.updateComplete;
    getPositionEventSpy.calls.reset();
})

it('should include an event listener for "resize"', async () => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    await component.updateComplete;
    expect(getPositionEventSpy.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
})
```

The problem comes when I try to test that the event listener is detached. I put this test in a separate describe block where I initiate a the `disconnectedCallback` function which should remove the event listener and then test that the spy has not been called when I dispatch the event:

```
describe('disconnection', () => {

    beforeAll(() => {
        component.disconnectedCallback();
        getPositionEventSpy.calls.reset();
    })

    it('should remove the "resize" event listener', async () => {
        expect(getPositionEventSpy.calls.count()).toEqual(0);

        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        await component.updateComplete;

        expect(getPositionEventSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    })

})
```

In this case the test fails meaning the `getPositionEventSpy` has been called. In trying to understand what's happening I added a `console.log("getting position")` statement in the `getPosition()` function. When I run the test for removing the event listener the console log statement doesn't get run, so I believe that the removal of the eventlistener is actually successful. So why does the spy count increase? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

try `spy.resetHistory()`

```
 beforeAll(() => {
        component.disconnectedCallback();
        getPositionEventSpy.resetHistory();
    })
```